# Is there any way to pass the javascript value to model in view

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using the css dropdown list for city how to pass the selected value of city to model in view

```
<span class='selected' id="SelectedCity">select City</span>
```

the selected value is in span how to pass the span value to model ?

I have used `$.post` method but it hits the action method twice second time it takes the value null for city

```
 $.post("/UserRegistration/CreateEducator", { city: cityTextValue });
```

Comment: need more code shown to understand why you are sending data twice

Comment: Please, add your Controller/Action header and your view code.

Comment: the data is posting twice one for $.post method and another for submit button if am giving type=button then model values are set to null

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple. In Java EE we generally use ***request.getparameter("parameter name")*** to retrieve values from views. 
The only thing you are required is to give a name to your input, select or drop down list.

Answer (score 0):

use `onchange` event for `Select`.

write script like this

```
function GetSelectedItem()
{
    var e = document.getElementById("select");
    var cityTextValue = "The Value is: " + e.options[e.selectedIndex].value + " and text is: " + e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
    alert(cityTextValue );
}
```

Hope this helps